# Appending the decimal automatically while typing in the UITextField

Tags: ios

I am having a UITextField in which I had limited the number of characters to 4 before decimal and 3 to after decimal. I have done this through

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
     replacementString:(NSString *)string{
        if (textField == txt_weightKg)
        {
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range 
        withString:string];

        NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]{1,4}+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,3})?)?$";

        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression 
         regularExpressionWithPattern:expression

                                                                                                                   options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                                 error:nil];
        NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                            options:0
                                                              range:NSMakeRange(0,
       [newString length])];
         if (numberOfMatches == 0)
            return NO;
        }

     return YES;
  }
```

This is only for keeping the validation but now I want i actually want is that As soon as I start typing in the UITextfield a decimal is automatically appended with the number. The second condition is that as I reaches the 4 digits the next digit should be after the decimal. For example:-

if I entered 1 it should look like 1. , for 2 digits 11. this has to continue up to 4 digits and then as soon as I eneter the fifth digit it should place that 5th digit after the decimal as 1111.1 which will continue to 3 places after decimal.

If somebody can help me then It will be greatly appreciated! feel free to ask in case of confusion.

Comment: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=numeric+textfield

Comment: I don' think this is particularly going to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i achieved what you required by following code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string

{
  //create character set containing numbers only
  NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet    characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];

      if (textField.text.length >= 8  && range.length == 0)
      {
         return NO;
      }
      else
      {

         if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {
              return NO;
         }
         else
         {
           int length = [textField.text length];
           //append a decimal after 4 digits
           if([textField.text length] ==4 && string.length != 0)
           {
              textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.",textField.text];
           }
           return YES;
        }
     }

}
```

Please confirm your response to this.

Comment: If we are adding a decimal by ourselves then also this code is appending an extra decimal after 4 digits which is not at all required in mathematics. Thanks for the logic but can You code this by keeping that condition also....

Comment: have you tested this properly... because for me it is working fine. According to my logic user cannot type anything other than number 0-9. Even if user tries to type text field will not accept that.

Comment: yes I have tested it properly as I have made the keyboard on these textfields as numeric keyboard and therefore I am getting the option of entering a decimal.

Comment: yes, you will get the option to type in but this method will return No in that case so it will not be typed in.

Comment: Yeah! it's working fine but what i actually want is that as soon as I type single digit in the text box a decimal should append itself after that digit and as soon as the number of digits reaches 4 the next digit should come after the decimal. Still the total number of digits should be 7 only. If you can do this then it will be amazing!!!!! thanks for the reply mate

Comment: replace the code within braces of second 'else' part with following code:                                                              if (0 <= textField.text.length && textField.text.length <= 4 && string.length != 0) {
                    NSArray* stringArray = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
                    NSString* str  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.",[stringArray objectAtIndex:0],string];
                    textField.text  = str;
                    return NO;
                }
            else
                return YES;

Comment: yeah! amit this is working fine but if someone wants to enter the value 11.11 only in this text field then this is all hard coded and it is also not allowing to write the above number. The logic is amazing but it is still not fulfilling my requirement of entering whatever number i want to enter with the decimal appended as in the code you have written above.

Comment: The requirement is confusing now. If user can see a decimal just after entering a digit, how can he decide whether the next digit which he is pressing is before or after decimal.As user see a decimal '.' already he is not going to press it again from keyboard.

Comment: Yeah! I understand it but we are providing a functionality which is similar to a windows software in which the user can place his cursor after the decimal and then agin starts typing the required number. For example: 1. If he types 11 then according to your logic it will look like 11. but now what i want is that he should be able to place his cursor after the Decimal and can type the number with still The three digit constraint after the decimal. i hope You understand the problem and ask freely If you are having some doubt. Thanks for bearing with my problem!